# How to write powershell script with Where-Object

Tags: c#, powershell

Given script like this :

```
Get-ADPermission -Identity "Mark Adam" | where {$._ExtendedRights -like "*Send-As*"} -and -not {$_.Users -like "NT AUTHORITY\SELF"}
```

Here I tried so far, still no luck.

```
var CommandGetAdPermission = new Command("Get-ADPermission");

CommandGetAdPermission.Parameters.Add("Identity", Identity);       

var CommandWhere = new Command("Where-Object");

ScriptBlock filter = ScriptBlock.Create("{$_.ExtendedRights -like \"*Send-As*\"} -and -not {$_.User -like \"NT AUTHORITY\\SELF\"}");

CommandWhere.Parameters.Add("FilterScript", filter);

pipeline.Commands.Add(CommandGetAdPermission);
pipeline.Commands.Add(CommandWhere);                     

psh = pipeline.Invoke();
errors = ps.Streams.Error.ReadAll();
```

Return error as below :

> The term 'Where-Object' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

Do I do something wrong?

Comment: Can you post the part where you create the runspace for your pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. In case of complex filtering (i.e. more than one criteria) you want to put whole filter criteria in script block like this:

```
Get-ADPermission -Identity "Mark Adam" | Where-Object {$_.ExtendedRights -like "*Send-As*" -and $_.Users -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SELF"}
```

There is also a typo with

```
$._ExtendedRights
```

while it has to be

```
$_.ExtendedRights
```